# It is possible to manage a Samba4 ADDC server with phpLDAPadmin?

Tags: linux, ldap, samba4

I have installed a Samba4 and configured it as a Active Directory Domain Controller and works GREAT. Now I wonder, it is possible to manage it with phpLDAPadmin instead of RSAT? I'm kicking all Windows-ses from my network!
Any help, link, tip, will be much appreciated.

So far, I'm able to read-only the ADDC, with phpLDAPadmin, but no more than that...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using Samba as a DC if you're trying to get rid of Windows from your network?

Comment: Where do I put all my users, accounts, groups, machines? I have some services[proxy, email and other services] and linux machines linked to that DC...

Comment: I found this, and it works -> https://github.com/jniltinho/go-samba4

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need it, this is new and works like a charm:

https://github.com/Universidad-Tecnologica-CUJAE/AD-webmanager

It is based on Python3+Flask.

Regards!